# Download Selected Rows in DT

Tags: shiny, dt

Is there any way to download selected rows with `buttons` extension? If not, is there any way to add custom buttons within the table at top left side? I know how to download selected rows. I found we can add custom button to select columns (https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/397)

I added 2 custom buttons (mentioned in the code below).

```
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'title')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('dashboard', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard'))
  )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
 fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(2,   
      actionButton("downloadData", "Download Selected Rows", icon = icon("download"), 
      style="color: #333; background-color: #FFF; border-color: #333")),
      useShinyalert(),
      column(2,  
      actionButton(inputId = "run", label = "Write Selected Rows to SQL", icon = icon("paper-plane"),
                       style="color: #333; background-color: #FFF; border-color: #333")),
     useShinyalert()
  )),

           box(
             title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
             DT::dataTableOutput('table2')  
  )
)

ui<-dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046948/exporting-only-selected-rows-from-dt/56090911#56090911

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting only Selected Rows from DT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046948/exporting-only-selected-rows-from-dt)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure in which format you wish to download the selected rows, but here is an example storing a csv-file based on the selection (you need a downloadButton):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'title')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('dashboard', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard'))
  )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidPage(fluidRow(
    column(2,   
           downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Selected Rows", icon = icon("download"), 
                          style="color: #333; background-color: #FFF; border-color: #333")),
    useShinyalert(),
    column(2,  
           actionButton(inputId = "run", label = "Write Selected Rows to SQL", icon = icon("paper-plane"),
                        style="color: #333; background-color: #FFF; border-color: #333")),
    useShinyalert()
  )),
  p(),
  box(
    title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
    DT::dataTableOutput('table2')  
  )
)

ui<-dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0(gsub(" ","_", gsub(":",".", Sys.time())),".csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.table(iris[input$table2_rows_selected,], file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I know how to download selected rows. But I want it to be done with buttons  extension of DT. Reason I want this is - I want download buttons to be displayed within the table ( not outside table)